# 13.04: Opening ubuntu one GUI

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-one

I am having trouble syncing files in Ubuntu One. I was going to connect and disconnect using the interface in previous versions but I can no longer access this.

I have a cloud in the top right of my monitor and this has "Open Ubuntu One" as the first option but nothing happens when I click that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the cloud, you should see the following menu

[image: Cloud Menu]

To activate/deactivate cloud, you should be able to click the top menu item. If this does not work, go to the System Settings and Click on the Ubuntu One icon

[image: Ubuntu One]

then when the main window appears, Click the <kbd>Connect/Disconnect</kbd> button on the right

[image]

Comment: On the first figure you show what I see is different. The icon is missing and a red circle with a dash replaces it. The Ubuntu One is also missing and currently 1.80 replaces it. In my System Settings there is no Ubuntu One icon

Comment: I removed QT5 a while ago if that has anything to do with it

Comment: You may need to launch the Software Center and Search for Ubuntu One and install it from there.

Comment: I was concerned it would try to install QT5 and remove QT4. Working now.

Comment: It obviously didn't. glad to be of assistance.